# Changing .center Property of UILabel in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I have a set of IBOutlet UILabels in my implementation file of an iOS app in Xcode 5. I put them into an NSMutableArray and try to access their property, .center, but cannot have the new center displayed on screen.

**Header:**

```
IBOutlet UILabel *label1 ;
IBOutlet UILabel *label2 ;

NSMutableArray *myArray
```

**Implementation:**

```
initWithNibName:
myArray = [NSMutableArray new] ;
[myArray addObject: label1] ;
[myArray addObject: label2] ;
```

When, in another method, I try to change the .center of the label in the array, nothing happens. I do so like such:

```
//"mylabel" is a UILabel property of the my class
_mylabel = [myArray objectAtIndex:0] ;    
_mylabel.center = CGPointMake(78,400);//nothing happens

//there isn't bad access because this works:
label1.center = CGPointMake(78,400) ;
```

Even with the UILabel my label defined in the method right there, still nothing happens.

```
UILabel *mylabel = [myArray objectAtIndex:0] ;    
mylabel.center = CGPointMake(78,400);  //nothing happens
```

`[myArray objectAtIndex:0].center` obviously doesn't work because the objects are of `id`.

How should I access the .center of the UILabels in an NSMutableArray and have the change displayed on the screen?

Comment: What is a `NSMutableArray *myArray`? Is it an ivar? 
are you sure that `myArray` ins't nil when you access it from the second method? Of it isn't nil - is `_mylabel == nil` after you get object from array?

Comment: Nothing is ever nil, at any time throughout the operation. And yes, the array is an Ivar

Comment: try to debug it. Add `NSLog(@"Label %p added to array %p", label1, myArray);` and `NSLog(@"Label %p from array %p", _mylabel, myArray);`. Compare pointers. It also look strange that you have an access using `label1` reference, it should be either `_label1` or `self.label1` if you haven't wrote custom `@synthesize` in implementation

Comment: I declared the Labels (1 and 2) in the parenthesis of @interface as they are outlets. I have debugged, but I think theproblem is tthat I made a second UILabel to equal the object in the array, so it isn't actually linked to the xib file. I'm still searching for how to directly access the object in the array. I think I've found something like: `[[myArray objectAtIndex:index] setBackgroundColor:color];` but with a setCenter method.

Comment: No, my above comment: `[[myArray objectAtIndex:index] setCenter:centerPoint];` does not work either. Accessing the UILabel, not from the array, works though, so it leads me to believe that the array is setup wrong or when an object is added, it is not the actually object, but a copy of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my problem. Make a `UILabel *myLabelArray[500]` (or whatever number) in the `@interface{
//outlets go here}`. Now assign all the UILabels to the array and when you try to access them, through the array, you can.

```
myLabelArray[0] = firstLabel ;
myLAbelArray[1] = secondLabel ;
...
```